# My text not add in list item in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HI I m creating a new form and fill some text and submit but my text not save

Can u please help me

If i click a button add new than show a form add details in the form and save but not save .

I m new in **ANgular**

My Code is this

**ANgular Js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.peopleName = '';
  $scope.peopleSex = '';
  $scope.peple=[
    {name:"Saml", sex:"M"},
    {name:"somi", sex:"M"},
    {name:"jokyineya", sex:"F"}
    ];


    $scope.newItem = function(name, sex){
      if (this.peopleName === '') return;
       $scope.peple.push({
            name: title,
            sex: label
        });
        this.peopleName= "";
        this.peopleSex= "";
        this.showForm = false;
    }

})
```

**HTML Code is**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="" ng-controller="myController">

    <form ng-submit="newItem(peopleName, peopleSex)" ng-show="showForm">

      Name
      <input type="text" ng-model="peopleName" />
      <br />
      <br />Sex
      <input type="text" ng-model="peopleSex" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Submit" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </form>

    <button ng-click="showForm=true; ">Add new</button>
    <ul>



      <li></li>
      <li ng-repeat="person in peple">
        {{person.name}} {{person.sex}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/e69pNXXE0Tg9EHUAfcYy?p=preview)**

Comment: Can you please tell me, where you want to save the data?

Comment: `this.peopleName` change this to `$scope.peopleName` - `this` may not be a reference to your controller scope in this context. Also, you pass in `name` and `sex` as parameters to the function but they're never used (and they're available in the $scope anyway so you don't need to)

Comment: @Rohit Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few change to be done

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/b9Wh5Fi3BmcIHsV4rWRF?p=preview)**

Change **title** to **name** and **label** to **sex** like as shown below

```
$scope.peple.push({
name: title,
sex: label
});
```

Change **button** to **submit**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.@NidishKrishana I like your answer Really greate men

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with 'title' and 'label':

```
$scope.newItem = function(name, sex){
  if (this.peopleName === '') return;
   $scope.peple.push({
        name: title, // this should be name
        sex: label // this should be sex
    });
    this.peopleName= "";
    this.peopleSex= "";
    this.showForm = false;
}
```

It should look like so:

```
$scope.newItem = function(name, sex){
  if (this.peopleName === '') return;
   $scope.peple.push({
        name: name,
        sex: sex
    });
    this.peopleName= "";
    this.peopleSex= "";
    this.showForm = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood some things here. But it is quite easy to fix.
When you use ng-model in your html you already have written them to the $scope, so you do not need to send them as parameters.

```
$scope.newItem = function(){
  if ($scope.peopleName === '') return;
   $scope.peple.push({
        name: $scope.peopleName,
        sex: $scope.peopleSex
    });
    $scope.peopleName= "";
    $scope.peopleSex= "";
    $scope.showForm=false;
}
```

And call it with

```
<form ng-submit="newItem()" ng-show="showForm">
```

you also need the button to submit as answered before.

Answer (score 0):

Change **html** to this:
`<form ng-submit="newItem()" ng-show="showForm">`
And `newItem` function as:

```
$scope.newItem = function(name, sex){
  if (this.peopleName === '') return;
   $scope.peple.push({
      name: $scope.peopleName,
      sex: $scope.peopleSex
  });
  $scope.peopleName= "";
  $scope.peopleSex= "";
  $scope.showForm = false;
}
```

Angularjs use `$scope` to binding value to html,so use it as posible, my suggest.